# Angularjs iu.mask validation input with date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, date

im learning angular and right now i created input (type:text) which should display date, and it have ui.mask like "99/99/9999", it has validation in module to not pass (unblock button) if there is a wrong date , i mean ex: 00/00/0000 or 12/12/1700, but the input dont show red frame, it displays like it is valid format, how can i show red frame based on module validation?

```
HTML
<input
    id="dob"
    type="text"
    class="form-control   cell-height  form-input"
    ng-model="createAccount.dob"
    ui-mask="99/99/9999"
    placeholder="D.O.B. (mm/dd/yyyy)"
    required/>

CONTROLLER
 var validateDob = function () {
        try {
            var date = moment.utc($scope.createAccount.dob, "MM/DD/YYYY");
            if ($scope.patient == null) $scope.patient = {};
            if (!date.utc().isValid()) return false;
            if (date.utc().date() == 0 || date.utc().year() == 0) return false;
            if (date.utc().isAfter(moment().utc())) return false;
            if (date.utc().isSame(moment().utc())) return false;
            if (!date.utc().isAfter(moment.utc().subtract(150, 'years'))) {
                return false;
            }
            $scope.createAccount.dateOfBirth = date.utc();//.format("YYYY/MM/DD");
            return true;

        }
        catch (err) {
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) In order to do a custom validation, you need to create a directive, not a controller.

When the validator return a false response, angular will put an ng-invalid class to you DOM Object. It will allow you to change the border color or the style of your invalid input

Answer (score 0):

there were easier way, ng-class - check if validateDob returning false, if yes, show validation frame.